# How to use the same step multiple time in java spring boo

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So I work on a tool in spring boot, I have a step that rename a file, I call this step multiple time but I got an error like :

> Duplicate step [renameFileStep] detected in execution of
> job=[myjob]. If either step fails, both will be executed again on
> restart.

It doesnt rly sound like an error, I think the framework detected that I use the same step multiple time so he execute it only once. But I dont want this behavior.

```
public class ItemRenameFileFlagTasklet implements Tasklet {
    private String OldFlagFileName;
    private String marque;
    public ItemRenameFileFlagTasklet(String OldFlagFileName,String marque){
        this.OldFlagFileName=OldFlagFileName;
        this.marque=marque;
    }
    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

        String newFlagFileName=OldFlagFileName.replace(".", this.marque+".");

        File oldFile=new File(OldFlagFileName);
        File newFile=new File(newFlagFileName);
        oldFile.renameTo(newFile);

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

my job looks like this :

```
@Bean public Job myJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs) {
     return jobs.get("myJob")
          .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
          .start(createFileStep1())
          .next(renameFileStep())
          .next(createFileStep2())
          .next(renameFileStep())
          .next(createFileStep3())
          .next(renameFileStep())
          .build(); 
    }
```

I tried to create one method for each file that I want to rename but it doesnt look very clean....

Comment: make sure that each time it has a different step name.